# Palett Jack trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry

I have bit of mechanical problem in real life that I need to solve by math. Not sure is this trigonometric problem or something else but here's what I have.

[image]
I'm not mathematician so don't blame me if I used incorrect markings on illustration above or not using proper terminology. Feel free to edit title or whatever is needed because this is the best I could do to explain. Anyway, I will try to explain the problem in my own way.

I have 3 lines, **R1A**, **AB** and **R2B** in 2D space (XY). Line **R1A** is rotating around point **R1** by angle **α** in negative direction (CCW). Line **R2B** is rotating around point **R2** by angle **β** in positive direction (CW). Points **A** and **B** are connected with a line of known length (**c** - distance **AB** has constant value). Coordinates of points in 2D space **A**, **R1** and **R2** are known and angles of rotation **α** and **β** are known.

How to find coordinates of point **B** (distance **R2B** works too instead) so when we rotate line **R1A** by **α** angle, line **R2B** rotates by **β** angle?

To visualize this (white values are known, **orange is not**):

[image]

Comment: If $R1$ and $R2$ are fixed in place, then just set the arc length travelled by $A$ equal to the arc length travelled by $B$.  Solve for angle $\beta$.

Comment: @Doug, Distance AB must be constant, like a rod connecting two mechanical parts. I don't know where point B is and not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you know the radii of the circles?

Comment: @Vasili, Only of left one... can be calculated as a distance between known coordinates of **R1** and **A**, but coordinates of point **B** are unknown, so radius of another circle around **R2** is also unknown. My goal is to find formula to get coordinates of point B. Course, max angle **R1AB** and **ABR2** is 180 degrees, so **α** and **β** are bit limited. In real case **α** and **β** can't go over 30 degrees for given direction of rotations.

Comment: So if the left circle has radius $r_1$ and the right one has radius $r_2$, the point $A$ travels $\alpha \cdot r_1= \beta \cdot r_2$ which should give you $r_2$

Comment: @Vasili, Makes sense. Let me try it and do some tests to check does it work.

Comment: @Vasili Yep, that worked and guess that's what Doug was talking about in the first comment. Thanx a million guys, saved my day! Consider posting that as answer so I can accept that as solution.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: Glad it worked! I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Doug also noted, we have a rigid rod $c$ with endpoints $A$ and $B$. Therefore, if you displace point $A$, point $B$ will be displaced by the same distance (assuming no other forces are applied/relevant).  Thus if the left circle has radius $r_1$ and the right one has radius $r_2$ and we use radian measure of angles, the following equation can be used to find  $r_2$: $$\alpha \cdot r_1=\beta \cdot r_2$$